# how do I know if the mouse pointer is on the HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dhtml

I have a timed event I want to behave differently accordingly to what HTML element the mouse pointer is on.
Is there a way, assuming I have the HTML element, to know if the mouse pointer is currently on top of it.
I am well aware of the onmouseover/onmouseout events and how to use them.
I am using JQuery.
I am obviously looking for some kind of flag, as I need to check a state and not handle an event.
**again, I know how to implement this with events.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in way to ping an element for the status of mouse hovering.

However, you can create one by updating a flag at mouseenter and mouseleave -- which is where [Brian Driscoll's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384808/brian-driscoll) suggestion of [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) comes in:

```
jQuery.fn.tracking = function () {
  this.data('hovering', false);

  this.hover(function () {
    $(this).data('hovering', true);
  }, function () {
    $(this).data('hovering', false);
  });

  return this;
};

jQuery.fn.hovering = function () {
  return this.data('hovering');
}
```

You'll need to initialize tracking for each element you care about:

```
$('#elem1,#elem2').tracking();
```

But then you can get the status of any of them:

```
if ($('#elem1').hovering()) {
    // ...
} else if ($('#elem2').hovering()) {
    // ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/amaxu3/edit

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into jQuery.hover()? http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @Radu - Itay wanted a solution in terms of the jQuery framework.

Comment: @Radu - it is just more elegant and less coding.

Comment: I know, I meant the .hover event. He mentioned that he didn't want that unless he was referring to onHover.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with document.elementFromPoint, although I believe there are some inconsistencies in older browser implementations (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#documentview).

```
$('#elem').mousemove(function(e){
    if (this == document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Or outside of a handler

```
if ($('#elem').get(0) == document.elementFromPoint(x, y)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Aside from that, the only other option that comes to mind is using event handlers to keep track of which element the mouse is over.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give name to html andme and on mouseover you need to check document.getelementsbyName. Then check what your are getting as output. Now you can take decision is it html control or asp.net.

When you use collObjects = object.getElementsByName("htmlcontrol") then compare id of both.

1 morething why you needed to check this in javascript. there may be some other solution for that. Just share with us.