# Show a divison on mousehover to some links and hide on mouseout : should not hide when mouse pointer is over the opend division

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links in a grid , on `hover` of these link a division is get opened , i want to `hide` the division on `mouse out` of link but only when pointer is not in opened div

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td> <a id='a1'> link-1</a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <a id='a2'> link-2</a>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <a id='a3'> link-3</a>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="arrow_box" style="width:200px;height:200px;display:none;">
<div style="width: 50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" id="dvSummary">
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">Division - 1</div>
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-left: 10px;">Division - 1</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 50px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" id="dvSummary11">
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-left: 12px;">Division - 3</div>
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-left: 10px;">Division - 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: white;
 border: 1px solid #c2e1f5;
 }
 .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content:" ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
 .arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(232, 250, 248, 0);
 border-top-color: white;
 border-width: 20px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 }
 .arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 21px;
 margin-left: -21px;
 }
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("a").hover(function (e) {
$(".arrow_box").css({
    top: e.pageY - $(".arrow_box").height() - 20,
    left: e.pageX
}).show();
}).mouseout(function () {

//here i don't want to hide if mouse pinter is not on opend div
$(".arrow_box").hide();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anubrij/pH973/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need , detect the mouse hover event , I used below post to detect that

[how do I know if the mouse pointer is on the HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399647/how-do-i-know-if-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-the-html-element)

This is how you should

```
$("a").hover(function (e) {
    $(".arrow_box").css({
        top: e.pageY - $(".arrow_box").height() - 20,
        left: e.pageX
    }).show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    console.log($('.arrow_box').hovering());
     if($('.arrow_box').hovering()==true)
     {
    $(".arrow_box").hide();
     }

     });
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/pH973/9/)

Comment: The `<div>` is not hiding when the cursor leaves it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1.When `mouse enter` the link the div should `open`

2.When `mouse out` from the opened div the div should `closed`

```
$("a").mouseenter(function (e) {
    $(".arrow_box").css({
        top: e.pageY - $(".arrow_box").height() - 20,
        left: e.pageX
    }).show();
});

$(".arrow_box").mouseout(function () {
    $(".arrow_box").hide();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pH973/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the hover and mouseout to the div also.

```
$("a, .arrow_box").hover(function (e) {
    $(".arrow_box")
       . css({ top: e.pageY - $(".arrow_box").height() - 20, left: e.pageX })
        .show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    // here i don't want to hide if mouse pinter is not on opend div.
    $(".arrow_box").hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Jquery hover provide both function mouseover and mouseout. see here http://api.jquery.com/hover/

so you do not have to user mouseout event after hover just check above link.